# Translate the statements

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

***Prime Gap Definition:*** $Prime(p) \land Prime(p + a) \land (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, p < n < p + a \Rightarrow \lnot Prime(n))$

A) “There are infinitely many prime gaps.”

B) "Eventually, all natural numbers are not prime gaps."

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around translating infinite and eventually and applying the prime gap definition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture claim A) by claiming that for every number that is a prime gap, there is a greater number that is also a prime gap. Now, in order to do so, it helps to first state exactly the formula that states that '$a$ is a prime gap'. That would be:

$\exists p (Prime(p) \land Prime(p + a) \land (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, p < n < p + a \Rightarrow \lnot Prime(n)))$

OK, so then the claim that for every number that is a prime gap, there is a greater number that is also a prime gap becomes:

$\forall a (PrimeGap(a) \to \exists b (b > a \land PrimeGap(b))$

i.e.:

$\forall a (\exists p (Prime(p) \land Prime(p + a) \land (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, p < n < p + a \Rightarrow \lnot Prime(n))) \to \exists b (b > a \land \exists p (Prime(p) \land Prime(p + b) \land (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, p < n < p + b \Rightarrow \lnot Prime(n))))$

Now, B) is a strange claim ... I am not sure what they mean by it ...